# Magento 2.4.1 Error: A non-numeric value encountered in Price.php

Tags: magento2, error

What could cause this error in system.log:

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 194 [] []
```

Comment: did you find the solution ? same issue form me on 2.4.2

Comment: @cap340 any luck? same in 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

this solves the problem but nobody has taken the effort of running the required tests for it to pass all checks (since 6 jan) so it will not be added, shame shame ;-)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31565/files

Answer (score 0):

I think it's paired with the following line in exception.log

`[2021-07-05 13:57:09] main.CRITICAL: The "catalog.leftnav" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The \"catalog.leftnav\" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. at /www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/ExceptionHandlerBlock.php:59)"} []`

Placing a line of logger in the vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php line 194, I can see that sometimes the $toPrice variable is an empty string. It should be numeric, hence the error.
But at the moment I can't determine the root cause. I'm getting this since 2.4.1, and now on 2.4.2.

Edit: found that the server is getting some requests containing the price as parameter, like this "&price=-10--9%2C-10%2C-100".
Price should be number-number, like "0-100". This breaks the flow in the price filter. I'm unsure of what cause the value of the parameter to be so bad, in frontend can't replicate. It's possibly made by bots

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error occured during import of bundle product via csv,

**Reason:** the special_price attribute must be in % value
(eg) 10 and not as a price value like 50000

**Solution:** U can delete the entry of corresponding product in the table catalog_product_entity